# One-to-many Eloquent relation: Query to filter based on related table's column values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables that look like this:

`stocks`:

```
id | name      | market_cap
1  | Microsoft | 5000
2  | Tesla     | 2000
```

This table has a one-to-many relationship with a table titled `stock_ratings`:

```
id | stock_id | measure | value
12 | 1        | revenue | 30
13 | 1        | dividend| 5
14 | 2        | revenue | 10
15 | 2        | dividend| 0
```

Now, let's say a user wants to get all stocks with `market_cap > 3000`, skip the first 20 results, and get the next 20. This works:

```
$query = Stock::where('market_cap', '>', 3000);
$stocks = $query->skip(20)->take(20)->get();
```

However, the user needs to also be able to query on the stock_ratings. So, let's say, in addition to the conditions above, he wants to find all stocks that have a `value > 20` for the `revenue` measure.

I have tried this, and it doesn't work. It returns the same list of stocks as it would without this additional condition.

```
$query = Stock::where('market_cap', '>', 3000);
$query = $query->with(['ratings' => function ($q) {
    $q->where('stock_ratings.measure', 'revenue');
    $q->where('stock_ratings.value', '>', 0);
}]);
$stocks = $query->skip(20)->take(20)->get();
```

This returns all stocks with `market_cap > 3000` regardless of the `value` and `measure` in the `stock_ratings` table. It returns stocks that have a negative `value` in `stock_ratings` where `measure = revenue` and it also returns rows that have no related rows in stock_ratings whatsoever.

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply a constraint in `with` it means the constraint is applied for which nested related records should be eager loaded and which should not be eager loaded.

However in your case you want to filter or apply constraint on the stocks based on values contained in related ratings.

So try this

```php
$query = Stock::where('market_cap', '>', 3000);

$query = $query->whereHas('ratings', function ($q) {
    $q->where('measure', 'revenue');
    $q->where('value', '>', 0);
})-with('ratings');

$stocks = $query->skip(20)->take(20)->get();
```

Read more at Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence